# Est-ce qu'on se tutoie?

Tags: discussion, faq, style

Question idiote, mais est-ce qu'on se tutoie ici, entre internautes; ou au moins entre 'réguliers' du site?

Because I'm English, I tend to drop into tutoiement as soon as possible: even pretty much straight away with people who are my age or younger. I'm not sure how that translates to the interwebs, or more specifically to this site.

Comment: By the way, a better word for "régulier" might have been "habitué".

Comment: @Brennan, yes. I'm wondering what to do in cases like this. I've asked a question, [here](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/79/convention-for-indicating-youd-like-an-ancilliary-translation/80#80).

Comment: There is a misconception English people only use the *tutoiement*. That's actually the other way around. The English informal second person singular has been in used in the past (thou/thee/thy/thine/thyself) just like the french (*tu/toi/ton/tien/toi-même*) but has been obsoleted by the formal plural *you*, embracing and extending the French usage. A similar difference exists between European Spanish which maintains *tú/vosotros* and South American which uses *vos/ustedes*.

Comment: Je déteste cette distinction "entre réguliers du site". Rien que ça, ça me fait sauter au plafond, et ça m'est très désagréable. Je déteste les clubs privés, et sincèrement, Stack en général, donne vraiment l'impression d'en être un. Il y a au moins cinquante articles sur internet qui s'en plaignent, et vu comme j'ai vu certaines questions ou réponses traitées avec un dédain infini, je suis assez d'accord. (J'ai dit "j'ai vu", j'ai pas dit "tout le monde")

Answer (score 31):

## Oui

Il n'y a pas encore de réponse claire à la question.
Donc j'en fais une. Je pense que sur ce site on ferait bien de se tutoyer par défaut.
Que ceux qui sont d'accord plussoient…

Comment: J'ai déjà reçu un ‘vous’, et ça fait très bizarre.

Comment: +1 Sur un site web fréquenté par de nombreux débutants, il est logique d'éliminer les difficulés inutiles, et en particulier les ambiguités du vouvoiement.

Comment: D'habitude, je penche naturellement pour le tutoiement. Mais ici, étant donné que beaucoup de gens sont "rudes" dirons-nous,ça ne fait qu'ajouter au malaise. Il y a au contraire besoin d'un peu de distances et de respect sur ce site. Et c'est bien la première fois de ma vie que je suis l'avocate du vouvoiement sur internet.

Comment: Vous faites comme tu veux !

Comment: Tous ces tutoiements sans vraiment se connaître, cela fait un peu trop communiste pour moi. Et l'anglais you n'est pas un tutoiement mais un vouvoiement permanent.

Answer (score 13):

Ca n'a rien d'une question idiote.
Je suppose qu'il n'y aura jamais de réponse absolue, d'autant plus que chaque personne, région, groupe a ses propres normes et susceptibilités... Par exemple, le tutoyement est de mise où je travaille; mais dans certaines familles, les enfants vouvoient les parents...

A priori Internet est un des ces groupes où le tutoyement est plus facile (à cause de l'anglais, sans doute, mais aussi parce que les différences d'âge sont moins visibles).

J'aurais aussi tendance à tutoyer très vite; mais une chose est sûre, il n'y a pas de risque de choquer qui que ce soit en le vouvoyant pour commencer. Sinon, le mimétisme marche bien: si quelqu'un me tutoye, je le tutoye également; même chose pour le vouvoyement.

Comment: Alors entre toi et moi c'est tout vu :)

Comment: Pas de problème, mais remarque que je t'ai laissé commencer :-)

Comment: Moi j'aurais plutôt dit _grâce_ à l'anglais :)

Comment: Les réguliers de FL&U n'auront aucun mal à tous s'attendre mutuellement, pour ce qui est de commencer, et c'est plutôt ce que m'a appris l'anglais (après des relations très chaleureuseusement inconfortables avec des professeurs).

Answer (score 6):

Le mieux, c'est de se fixer soi-même une position de base, un comportement par défaut, mais de s'adapter à ses interlocuteurs. Personnellement, généralement, je tutoie ceux qui me tutoient, et je vouvoie ceux qui me vouvoient. Et si c'est moi qui lance la conversation, je vais plutôt vouvoyer, personnellement.

Comment: Exactement !!!!

Answer (score 4):

Sur les forums/chats internet le vouvoiement ressemble souvent à de la condescendance, a du mépris, à un manque d'aise avec les « nouvelles technologies, » ou un manque de naturel.
Je pense qu'il est tout-à-fait acceptable, et même préférable de tutoyer ici.

Et quel que soit le choix de la communauté, la FAQ devrait en faire part.

Comment: Ou bien à de la déférence.

Answer (score 4):

Just another "Oui, on se tutoie!", because nobody did speak about the *nétiquette*. The *nétiquette* convention is that the *tutoiement* is used on forums.

> En francophonie, on utilise fréquemment le tutoiement sur les forums, ou les chats, sans que cela soit considéré comme grossier ou familier, mais le vouvoiement pour les correspondances plus formelles.

(["Nétiquette" on wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9tiquette#Politesse))

Answer (score 1):

J'aurais tendance à penser qu'il n'y a pas de problème à laisser chacun décider pour soi-même selon les collègues qu'il peut avoir et de n'empêcher l'adhérence de personne en raison d'un tutoiement forcé. Pourquoi éliminer le vouvoiement? Pourquoi ne pas faire comme les anglais qui se sont débarrassés de leur « thou » pour ne garder que le « you », qui est réellement « vous »?

Comment: Pourquoi c'est downvoté? C'est une opinion, sage en plus. Pourquoi faire du tutoiement forcé quand on sait que c'est très désagréable à certaines personnes? Pourquoi ne pas laisser le choix comme dit ce message, Encore une preuve pour moi du manque de respect de l'utilisateur de base qui règne ici. ça veut paraître sympa un tutoiement, mais ça peut aussi être une agression.

Comment: @Quidam C'est un vote dû  soit à  l'une soit à  l'autre de deux tendances d'un courant d'esprit  qui veut que les échanges sur les réseaux sociaux et les forums soient sur la base du tutoiement, l'une promue par des gens sans idéal particulier mais gagnés à l'idée que cela est souhaitables, l'autre par des gens plus sérieusement motivés et qui particulièrement en ce qui a trait aux forums  voient dans le tutoiement la concrétisation d'une notion d'esprit de corps de la sorte dont sont empreintes certaines confréries, où les membres sont des « pairs » ou « frères » comme chez les maçons ; (1/2)

Comment: @Quidam  l'« erreur » est de ne pas considérer cela comme étant le seul point de vue possible, ce qui à mon avis n'est pas une erreur mais seulement un parti pris pour  un autre point de vue. (2/2)

Comment: Il faut donner le choix à chacun, oui. Et faire en sorte que ce forum soit plus sympa (je ne parla pas particulièrement du forum français, mais de l'état d'esprit pourri en général, envers les nouveaux, envers les réponses incomplètes etc...)

Comment: @Quidam Je ne suis pas conscient d'un esprit pourri envers les nouveaux en ce qui concerne le FSE; il me semble que les utilisateurs au courant soient en fait très aimables avec les nouveaux venus ; il se trouve peut-être que votre cas est particulier et que vous ayez eu affaire à un nombre inhabituel de membres peu coopératifs et/ou malpolis ou que vous ayez trouvé un certain nombre de ces cas dans vos lectures des questions dans le passé.

Comment: Ce n'est pas mon cas particulier, il y a au moins 50 pages sur internet de gens qui s'en plaignent, et j'ai pu l'observer également. Pas forcément directement, mais dans des commentaires que j'ai vu après coups, c'est-à-dire que j'arrive sur une question (pas posée par moi), je lis les commentaires et je vois des choses vraiment honteuses. Des questions qui sont refusées sans raison, des réponses qui sont downvotées juste parce qu'il manque une petite précision, etc, etc. C'est une chose très connue concernant Stackexchange, faites des recherches sur Google, vous verrez.

Comment: @Quidam Je dois reconnaitre qu'il y a des gens qui votent à la tête du client ; je suis moi-même victime d'une multitude de votes négatifs pour des trivialités (non signalées) ou simplement sans raison du tout ; peut-être 95 % de ces votes sont faits sans donner une seule raison.

Comment: C'est ce que je déteste ici. Je donne des votes négatifs aussi, mais j'essaye toujours de laisser un message pour signaler ce qui ne m'a pas plus dans une réponse. Comme cela, on peut discuter comme des êtres humains, et débattre, et si la personne s'est trompée, elle peut rectifier le tir, éditer sa question, et moi, enlever mon vote négatif (si c'est elle qui a tort et pas moi)

Comment: @Quidam Excellente façon de procéder